# Use break in for in loop to max to 10 properties

Tags: javascript

I want to show max 10 properties of window.document on my screen. But it still shows me all properties. This is my code.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="divResult></div>
  <script>
   var text = ""; 
   for (let i in window.document){
    if(i === 10) {
    break;
   }
   text += `${i} : ${window.document[i]} <br/>`;
   } 
   document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML = text;
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `i` a number?

Comment: I see couple of problems. 1. you are iterating an object whose property (i) is not same as Array(number). 2. To fix this you can add a counter. as in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the value of `i`, you'll see that it's not a number and so can never equal 10. That's why your loop reads all elements in `window.document`.

To achieve what you want, declare and initialize`var i` outside the loop and represent individual `window.document` elements with another variable like so:

```
var text = ""; 
var i = 0;
for (let j in window.document){
    if(i == 10) {
        break;
    }
    text += `${j} : ${window.document[j]} <br />`;
    i++;
}
document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Indeed it's a string. I understand. Well explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment this would help you.

```js
function populateDocDetails() {
var count = 0;
var retVal = [];
   for (let i in window.document){
    if(count === 10) {
    break;
   }
   count = count + 1;
   retVal.push({[i]:window.document[i]})
   }
   return retVal;
}

   document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(populateDocDetails());
```

```html
  <div id="divResult"></div>
```

Comment: `As mentioned in the comment` please copy your comment to your answer, so the information is all in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

`for (let i in window.document)` when you do this, then `i` will not be a loop counter. You are iterating over each *key* from the `window.document` object:

```js
let obj = { 
  firstName: "Fred", 
  lastName: "Bloggs", 
  age: 42,
  1: "some data",
  2: "some other data"
}

for (let i in obj) {
  console.log(typeof i, i, obj[i]);
}
```

Furthermore, as you can see, keys are *strings*, so your check `if(i === 10)` will never succeed, even if there was a property called `10`, since it will try to compare `"10" === 10` which will always return `false` because the two variables are different.

With a `for-in` loop, you need to maintain a separate counter. In addition, you probably should avoid using `i` as a variable - it's most commonly used as a loop counter, so when it isn't, it cold be confusing. It might even be what tripped you up here.

```js
var text = "";

let i = 1; //initialise the counter
for (let propertyName in window.document) {
  if (i === 11) {//stop after 10
    break;
  }
  text += `${i} : ${window.document[propertyName]} <br/>`;
  i++; //increment the counter
}
document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="divResult"></div>
</body>

</html>
```